# npm install failing inside of Docker container

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to get `npm install` working inside of Docker container(s) on my system...

I've tried the following containers:

- `nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs12`
- `nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.8-nodejs12-alpine`
- `minideb:stretch` (installed with nvm)

And they all have the same error. When I try to install an npm package, it will have an error that looks something like this:

```sh
# npm install -g typescript                                                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ipt":"next","tsd":"la'                                                                                                                                

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                                                                               
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T03_42_16_003Z-debug.log
```

If I run something like `npm cache clean --force`, and run the install command again, it'll fail at some other point in parsing the JSON.

The funny thing is that sometimes if it's a really small package it'll install it without any issues:

```sh
# npm install padleft                                                                                                                                                                                   [12/1883]
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for padleft@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":"6.3.1","npm":"3.10.6"} (current: {"node":"12.14.1","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: padleft@0.2.0
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.

+ padleft@0.2.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 2 packages in 1.472s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

It almost seems like it's failing if it can't install something if it doesn't download super fast. I've tried different versions of node/npm with nvm and it all does the same thing. On my host machine, npm works fine. Just having issues within all the Docker containers. I just had it fail with an nvm installed version on another Docker container based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess that Container is dropping packets.

Try adding more CPUs to the containers.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

If you are willing to trying other things: in case you Not chosen "host mode networking" try that.

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: That is host-mode networking.  Instead of asking the container to do  all the work of network-packets (which Kernels are really robust at.. while containers suck).  Good!  It fixed it.

Comment: So the problem is that when I use the host mode, I can't forward ports like I need to. I tried pinning CPUs to the container and that didn't help.

Comment: I can install things with apt-get or pip install all day, the only thing that won't work is npm. I don't understand. If I ping google.com and leave it running, I never drop packets or anything.

Comment: Great point.  I'll publicly admit that i've hated working with NPM and JS-based Client-side rendering.  Nothing is rock-solid, and everything is always suspect. -- Also, maybe you want to give something like Parallels or Oracle VirtualBox (free) to ensure Virtualization makes the container's code robust